# How to reverse engineer an apk without changing its siging information

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, apksigner

Suppose I have an an `apk` that I want to `reverse engineer` but there are some small problems regarding this. For instance if the application uses **Google siging mechanism** to **signin** into the app then I would not be able to signin after modifying the apk!
There are also couple of other reasons that why not to modify an apk with resigning it with custom keystore...!

**Is it possible?
Or is there any other problem to tackle this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible<sup>1</sup> to modify an APK without invalidating the signature.  That is the whole point of the signature.

However, the APK signature and Google's Sign-in service are different things.  "Signing" and "sign-in" are different words with different meanings.  From a theoretical standpoint (at least) an APK that has been modified should still be able to successfully use Google Sign-in.

Here are some background links on APK digital signatures and how they work:

- Wikipedia: [Digital signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)
- [APK Signature Scheme v2](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2)
- [APK Signature Scheme v3](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3)

---

<sup>1 - At least not currently.  If someone manages to break the "crypto" that is used to implement the signature, then all bets are off.  But we are probably OK for a few years ...</sup>

Comment: If somebody manages to break that crypto, we've got a lot bigger problems.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- I agree with you... But can you explain how siging works or at least point to some informative online resources?